# How to add Point to MatOfPoint2f?

Tags: android, opencv

My goal is to calculate the fundamental Matrix by using the matching keypoints from two images. Now I got the good matching points:

```
MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
matcher.match(descriptor1,descriptor2, matches);

List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
List<DMatch> good_matches = new ArrayList<DMatch>();
org.opencv.core.Point pt1;
org.opencv.core.Point pt2;

//Then I definite good_dist here
//....


for(int i =0;i<matchesList.size(); i++)
 {
  if(matchesList.get(i).distance<good_dist)
  {
     good_matches.add(matchesList.get(i));
     pt1 = keypoints1.toList().get(matchesList.get(i).queryIdx).pt; 
     pt2 = keypoints2.toList().get(matchesList.get(i).trainIdx).pt;
  }
}
```

Now I want to pass the pt1 and pt2 to MatOfPoint2f in order to call the function:

```
Calib3d.findFundamentalMat(pt1, pt2, Calib3d.FM_8POINT);
```

Does anyone know what should I do?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create Array of point (`array_point`) and do next:

```
MatOfPoint2f yourArray_of_MatofPoint2f= new MatOfPoint2f(array_point);
```

This is from Java, if this doesn't work, please post.

Comment: How to create Array of Point

Answer (score 0):

So we effectively start with `List<DMatch> good_matches`. You then want to  add your pt1 and pt2 Point objects to lists inside of your "`(matchesList.get(i).distance<good_dist)`" if statement, as in  `List<org.opencv.core.Point>`. We then have

```
List<DMatch> good_matches;
List<org.opencv.core.Point> points1;
List<org.opencv.core.Point> points2;
```

We then convert the lists of points to `MatOfPoint2f` as follows:

```
org.opencv.core.Point goodPointArray1[] = new org.opencv.core.Point[goodKeyPoints1.size()];
goodKeyPoints1.toArray(goodPointArray1);
MatOfPoint2f keypoints1Mat2f = new MatOfPoint2f(goodPointArray1);
```

I am sure more efficient ways of doing this exist, and I would love to hear them